# Affine transformation in image processing

Tags: image, algorithm, digital

Reading the below:

[image]

Example input image:

[image]

Affine matrix:

[image: Matrix]

Output:

[image: Output]

Is this output correct?
If I try to apply the formula above I get a different answer.
For example pixel: 20 at (2,0)
x’ = 2*2 + 0*0 + 0 = 4
y’ = 0*2 + 1*y + 0 = 0
So the new coordinates should be (4,0) instead of (1,0)
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the output is wrong, indeed, and your reasoning looks correct. You would get that output if a0 was 0.5 instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a loop it's possible that you are overwriting cells before you have a chance to adjust their values.

You'll want to ensure that you allocate a new matrix and then loop over the old matrix in order to set the new matrix's values.

Comment: I am getting a different output than the one given in the example, because of the way I understand how this works as explained with an example pixel. Am I getting the formula wrong or their output is invalid?